# Is AIC good enough for model selection between GLS and LM?

Tags: regression, aic, likelihood-ratio, lm, generalized-least-squares

I am currently fitting some generalized least squares (GLS) models and some linear models (LM) on the same dataset. The main difference is that GLS include a spatial autocorrelation matrix. I would like to know if AIC values are enough to select the best model of each set, or whether a likelihood-ratio test would be better.

Comment: GLS is an estimation technique, while LM is a model. As such, your comparison is one of apples and oranges. Instead of LM, do you perhaps mean OLS? On another note, AIC should be used for models estimated using maximum likelihood. But I guess it is possible to define data distributions in ways to make OLS and GLS maximum likelihood estimators, though, so that should not be a problem. (OLS: just assume homoskedasticity, lack of autocorrelation and normality of the error term. GLS: I guess, assume normality and specific forms of heteroskedasticity and/or autocorrelation in errors.)